# user_objects oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, user-object

I would just like to ask what is the difference between `user_constraints` and `user_objects`.

I have two databases and run a script on both DB that resulted a unique constraint error.

To solve the problem I deleted the constraint on `user_constraint` table for both DB.
After that DB1 run without error. DB2 however failed, I checked the `user_constraint` for both db and the constraints was deleted.

I was asked to check the `user_objects` and found that DB2 has that same `constraint_name` as the `object_name` in the `user_objects` table.

Any info regarding their relationship, use, similarites, etc will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: how do you did "To solve the problem I delete the constraint on user_constraint table for both DB" ? a delete statement?

Comment: @FlorinGhita Sorry wrong use of word... I use drop constraint <constraint_name>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint should be dropped with:

```
Alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name;
```

The difference is simple: User_objects contains all the objects in database and user_constraints contains only the constraints.

Comment: I see.. I guess it is better to check user_objects first when getting the unique_constraint error?

Comment: you've dropped the constraint and you see it in the user_objects. This can't be. Probably is another object.

Comment: It was a unique index in user_objects.. so I have to drop the index to make the script execute successfully.